# App Script: how to retrieve the current FilterCriteria for a Slicer without setting current filters as default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

A google sheet currently provides a slicer that filters a column by day of the week. I am able to retrieve the single slicer from the current sheet `slicer = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()getSheetByName('Attendance Register').getSlicers()[0]`. I then get the filter criteria as `fc = slicer.getFilterCriteria()` and, interestingly enough, the only non-empty or null attribute is `to_remove = fc.getHiddenValues()`. This is fine as it still allows me to filter data using an AppScript function.

The problem that I am facing is that `to_remove` does not give the current values to exclude from the slicer. In order for that to happen, the user must right-click on the slicer each time select "Set current filters as default". For the end-user it would be inconvenient to do this and most are likely to forget.

Is there a way around this such as saving the current state of the sheet on edit? Perhaps a separate function can be triggered `onEdit` that would be able to update things such as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()getSheetByName('Attendance Register').getSlicers()[0]` actually returns the current slicer that we are seeing as opposed to the saved slicer.

Plan B is to discard the slicer and try to focus on retrieving values from column filters.

### EDIT:

The below code filters all rows based on column 7. Column 7 contains the day of the week. The day of the week to be filtered for is provided by the end user either via a slicer or filter but not both. The filtered rows are then moved over to a new sheet and attendance (boolean column) is reset to False for the transferred rows.

The below code only works if I delete the slicer and set `USE_SLICER = false`. This is due to the slicer's inability to provide up to date filter values for `var vals2remove = getVals2removeFromSlicer(source)` whereas the filter does. This is bizarre as I would have thought that the `Slicer` class inherited from the `Filter` class as to inherit all if working class methods. This does not seem to be the case.

So I have gone with Plan B but would still love to know whether these exists a way to make the slicer return up to date filter values that reflect what the user has currently put in without the user having to select "Set current filters as default" on the slicer object.

```
USE_SLICER = false;


function getVals2removeFromSlicer(sheet){
  return sheet.getSlicers()[0].getFilterCriteria().getHiddenValues();
}


function getVals2removeFromColFilter(sheet,col_num){
  return sheet.getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(col_num).getHiddenValues();
}



function filteredRegister2database(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Attendance Register');
  var sink = ss.getSheetByName('Attendance data'); 
  const colIdx2filter = 7 
  if (USE_SLICER){
    var vals2remove = getVals2removeFromSlicer(source);
  } else {
    var vals2remove = getVals2removeFromColFilter(source,colIdx2filter);
  }
  const data = source.getRange('A3:K').getValues();
  var filtered_data = [];
  var new_bool_col = [];
  for (var row of data){
    if (vals2remove.includes(row[colIdx2filter-1])){  // indices start counting at zero as opposed to one for sheet columns
      new_bool_col.push([row[8]]);
      continue;
    }
    filtered_data.push(row);
    new_bool_col.push([false]);
  }
  const sink_start_idx = sink.getLastRow() + 1;  // where to start appending
  const sink_end_idx = sink_start_idx + filtered_data.length - 1;
  sink.getRange(`A${sink_start_idx}:K${sink_end_idx}`).setValues(filtered_data); // append; no overwrite
  source.getRange(`I${3}:I${3+data.length-1}`).setValues(new_bool_col);
}
```

Lastly, here is a screenshot as to illustrate what is meant by "Set current filters as default on the slicer object"

[image: slicer]

Comment: Can you share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we can better understand your situation and easily replicate it

Comment: I think that in the current stage when you want to retrieve the value of the slicer and the filtered rows by the slicer using a script, it is required to set "Set current filters as default". Because before "Set current filters as default", the situation of the sheet is for only the user who opens the Spreadsheet. By "Set current filters as default", the current slicer is reflected in the sheet and the value of the slicer can be retrieved by the script.

Comment: So, in this case, "Plan B" might be required to be selected. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your "Plan B". Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: @Tanaike I have included the implementation of Plan B above.

Comment: @Logan unfortunately, the original sheet contains personal information. A such, I have not shared it. However, have included the full script of the function that I would like  to implement. It works when I do not rely on the slicer.

Comment: @DylanSolms You can share a dummy sheet, replace sensitive data with dummy data

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `make the slicer return up to date filter values that reflect what the user has currently put in without the user having to select "Set current filters as default" on the slicer object` from your updated question. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: @Tanaike When one has a Slicer on the sheet then the user clicks on it. A dropdown list provides options. A user clicks on the options and the data filters. The user sees filtered data. I would like to retrieve the state of the slicer after the user has clicked on it. But the slicer in the AppScript does not reflect what the user has selected. It only reflects the default values. If the user saves the current setting as default values then only does it reflect in the AppScript. I have attached a screenshot of what is meant by this and "Set current filters as default".

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my understanding of your reply is correct, unfortunately, in the current stage, that can't be achieved as I have already mentioned in my 1st comment. If you want to retrieve the values of the current slicer, it is required to set "Set current filters as default". So, I asked about your "Plan B". If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: I have implemented the Plan B in my above code. When I set `USE_SLICER = false` then I run Plan B but when `USE_SLICER = true` then I run Plan A. So minimal change is actually made. However, a slicer looks nice. I would have thought that the `Filter` class was a parent class to `Slicer` such that a slicer would behave like it and be able to save the current state. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed from your reply. I apologize for the late reply. From your reply, I understood that your "Plan B" works as a workaround. I'm glad about it. Unfortunately, in the current stage, in the case of Slicer, in order to retrieve the current sheet by Slicer, it seems that it is required to do `Set current filters as default`.